# subsetting a dataframe with conditions for a lot of columns

Tags: r, subset

For subsetting dataframes with multiple conditions, one could use

```
#my condition
x=1

a=dat[dat[,1]>x&dat[,2]>x,]
```

This time I'm facing quite a lot of columns that I have to check. I tried the following examples but could'd find a way to get it working

```
a=dat[dat[,1:10]>x,]
d=dat[which(dat$V1:dat$V10>x)]
c=subset(dat,dat$V1:dat$V10>x)
```

They basically all produce the same error:

```
numerical expression has XXX elements: only the first used
```

Does anyone know a way around?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the rows for which `dat$V1>1 & ... & dat$V10>1` without repeating the `&` in  the code?
You can, for example, use:

```
dat[apply(dat[,1:10]>x,1,all) , ]
```

Comment: thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for!